# pdf to png or jpg conversion and back again with php - losing fonts

Tags: php, pdf

I need to accept hundreds of pdfs at a time via PHP.  I am storing these files on S3, so, file size will become a concern - not only for storing, but general handling.  I'm finding the best way to reduce file size is conversion from PDF to PNG and back to PDF.  A 15M file drops to 700kb.  The problem is I'm losing certain fonts.  Is there a way to ensure this doesn't happen? How do I ensure the process I use maintains the fonts in the original document?  Is there some massive font library I can install?

from the command line I've tried...

Imagemagick
Ghostscript
pdftk
inkscape (real nice output)

They all work with varying levels of success, but each of them lose certain fonts - and not always the same ones.

Comment: You're most likely losing fonts which haven't been embedded. As a starting point, try running `pdffonts` utility from xpdf on problematic PDF's. This will summarize all fonts and which have and haven't been embedded.

Answer (score 1):

*Nope!*

The **.PDF** format is an encapsulation of "graphics commands," such as *"render the following text at position (X,Y) in the workspace using font Z."*

When you "convert" such a file to *any(!)* "image file" format, you are in fact asking the PDF-engine to "carry out those graphics commands," producing a bitmap *(a rectangular grid of pixels ...)* as its only output.

Well, once you have done *that,* "you can never go back."  The PDF-engine rendered its rectangular grid of pixels as best it could, and now, both it and the PDF-file that it consumed are *gone,* leaving you only with a rectangular grid of (output) pixels.

Comment: Dont know if i completely understand mike. Rectangular boxes werent rendered, fonts were substituted. Differenty by each applincation. Installing mscore fonts on the system fixed the issue however.